# Random die simulator

Tags: java, random, die

Hello stackoverflow you're always so nice and helpful.
I've encountered another compiling-problem with my random-diesimulator;

```
public class dieSimulator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        die();
    }
    public static int die()
    {
        generator.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
}
```

It's basically supposed to generate a random int between 1 and 6 each time the program is run.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:
Thank you, here's my current code, still giving me the compiler-error:
error: cannot find symbol
        return generator.nextInt(6)+1;
               ^
  symbol:   variable generator

```
public class dieSimulator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int rollValue = die();
        System.out.println(rollValue);
    }
    public static int die()
    {
        return generator.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
}
```

The book I'm currently reading tells me that ",the call generator.nextInt(6) gives you a random number between 0 and 5".

EDIT END;
The final code that made the magic happen

```
    import java.util.Random;

public class dieSimulator
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int rollValue = die();
        System.out.println(rollValue);
    }
    public static int die()
    {
        Random generator = new Random();
        return generator.nextInt(6)+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `generator`, and where is it defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `return` the generated value because `die()` has a return type of `int` but there is no return statement in the method, thus throwing a compilation error .

```
public static int die()
{
    return generator.nextInt(6)+1; // return the value
}
```

And you need to assign the returned value to some int variable(so that you can use it later) in the caller method.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int rollValue = die();
    // Do something with rollValue 
}
```

---

> Q. Thank you, here's my current code, still giving me the compiler-error: error: cannot find symbol return generator.nextInt(6)+1; ^ symbol: variable generator

Since you don't have the `generator` defined anywhere in the class, it is not able to find it. It should be defined in your class. Something like this

```
public class dieSimulator
{
    Random generator = new Random(); //Just as an example
    ...
```

Comment: @MarounMaroun Yes. Just like me. :P +1

Comment: Because I just had a cup of coffee? ;)

Answer (score 1):

you missed return statement..

```
public static int die()
{
    return generator.nextInt(6)+1;
}
```

Comment: And assign the returned value in `main`.